# Elasticsearch sorting the data by using keywords

Tags: elasticsearch

I am a noobie in elasticsearc.

Recently I am doing a research for the keyword search. I already done a version for the mysql with php. But I don't have idea how to do it in elasticsearch by using its default functions.

Here is the data format:

```
[{"id":"1","keyword":["A","B"]},
 {"id":"2","keyword":["A","C"]}
]
```

Basically those keywords work as hashtag for searching to find out the data.
And I had to take the most keyword hits in the records and sort them according to how many keyword they got hit.

In this example, if I input "A B" for searching in this example, I will get the result as:

```
[{"id":"1","id":"2"}]
```

id 1 record hits two keywords and become the first record in the ordering, 
id 2 record hits only one keyword and become the second record.

How can I do it in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "keyword": "A B"
        }
    }
}
```